# Why this algorithm always works? Minimum operations required to make each row and column of matrix equals

Tags: algorithm

Given a square matrix of size n x n. Find minimum number of operation are required such that sum of elements on each row and column becomes equals. In one operation, increment any value of cell of matrix by 1. In first line print minimum operation required and in next ‘n’ lines print ‘n’ integers representing the final matrix after operation.

Input:

1 2
3 4

Output:

4
4 3
3 4

Explanation

1. Increment value of cell(0, 0) by 3
2. Increment value of cell(0, 1) by 1
   Hence total 4 operation are required

Input: 9

1 2 3
4 2 3
3 2 1

Output:

6
2 4 3
 
4 2 3 
3 3 3

Solution explanation:

The approach is simple, let’s assume that maxSum is the maximum sum among all rows and columns. We just need to increment some cells such that the sum of any row or column becomes ‘maxSum’.
Let’s say Xi is the total number of operation needed to make the sum on row ‘i’ equals to maxSum and Yj is the total number of operation needed to make the sum on column ‘j’ equals to maxSum. Since Xi = Yj so we need to work at any one of them according to the condition.

In order to minimise Xi, we need to choose the maximum from rowSumi and colSumj as it will surely lead to minimum operation. After that, increment ‘i’ or ‘j’ according to the condition satisfied after increment.

Below is the implementation of the above approach.

Solution Code:

```
// Java Program to Find minimum 
// number of operation required 
// such that sum of elements on 
// each row and column becomes same
import java.io.*;

class GFG {

// Function to find minimum
// operation required
// to make sum of each row
// and column equals
static int findMinOpeartion(int matrix[][],
                                     int n)
{
    // Initialize the sumRow[]
    // and sumCol[] array to 0
    int[] sumRow = new int[n];
    int[] sumCol = new int[n];

    // Calculate sumRow[] and
    // sumCol[] array
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)

        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        {
            sumRow[i] += matrix[i][j];
            sumCol[j] += matrix[i][j];
        }

    // Find maximum sum value 
    // in either row or in column
    int maxSum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) 
    {
        maxSum = Math.max(maxSum, sumRow[i]);
        maxSum = Math.max(maxSum, sumCol[i]);
    }

    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < n && j < n;) 
    {
        // Find minimum increment
        // required in either row
        // or column
        int diff = Math.min(maxSum - sumRow[i],
                    maxSum - sumCol[j]);

        // Add difference in 
        // corresponding cell,
        // sumRow[] and sumCol[]
        // array
        matrix[i][j] += diff;
        sumRow[i] += diff;
        sumCol[j] += diff;

        // Update the count 
        // variable
        count += diff;

        // If ith row satisfied,
        // increment ith value 
        // for next iteration
        if (sumRow[i] == maxSum)
            ++i;

        // If jth column satisfied, 
        // increment jth value for
        // next iteration
        if (sumCol[j] == maxSum)
            ++j;
    }
    return count;
}

// Utility function to 
// print matrix
static void printMatrix(int matrix[][],
                                 int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            System.out.print(matrix[i][j] +
                                       " ");

        System.out.println();
    }
}

/* Driver program */
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int matrix[][] = {{1, 2},
                      {3, 4}};

    System.out.println(findMinOpeartion(matrix, 2));
    printMatrix(matrix, 2);

}
}

// This code is contributed by Gitanjali.
```

**My Question:**

I don't understand why this code works with all cases. It's not obvious to me, why to solve the problem I can just start from the top left corner of the matrix and solve greedily the whole problem, without checking what would happen if I started from some other position like for example the bottom left corner or top right corner. When I solved some examples from different starting position I would get a different matrix but correct in the terms of equality of row and columns, but it's a little magic for me why that is happening. Any suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be expressed as follows.

Suppose we have n people picking strawberries, and n baskets.  Our aim is that each person picks the same number, and each basket has the same number (with the minimum number of extra strawberries picked.

The matrix A[i,j] represents the number of strawberries that person i has placed into basket j.

The idea is that we can achieve this aim by simply asking any person who still has work to do to place a strawberry into any basket that is not full.

i.e. it doesn't matter which person or which basket is chosen as long as they still have space.  The order chosen in the algorithm given makes it easy to keep track of which people and baskets have space.

Comment: Omg! This is amazing explanation. Thank you very much sir! :)